# VBA function to Concatenate sentence up to nth Character Limit with Delimiter

Tags: excel, regex, vba

This is an EXCEL VBA question but related to regular expression.

I have a VBA code like below, which takes rows of string from one column and joins them together while separating them with a delimiter and outputting it in another cell. It also tries to make sure each rows of string doesn't surpass a certain maximum limit. In which case it separates not at the maximum character position, but instead in the closest white space prior to reaching the nth character (max character limit).

```
Sub Col_No_Blanks()
  Dim RX As Object
  Dim Col As Variant, itm As Variant
  Dim Txt As String
 
  Const Delim As String = "/"
  Const CharsBeforeDelim As Long = 10
  Const ContiguousColOfCells As String = "A2:A5"
  Const OutputCell As String = "B2"
 
  Set RX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  RX.Global = True
  RX.Pattern = "(^.{1," & CharsBeforeDelim & "}(\s))(?=.+)"
  Col = Range(ContiguousColOfCells).Value
  For Each itm In Col
    If Len(itm) Then Txt = Txt & Delim & RX.Replace(itm, "$1" & Delim)
  Next itm
  Range(OutputCell).Value = Mid(Txt, Len(Delim) + 1)
End Sub
```

I think my problem is with the regular expression. Although it does avoid breaking a whole word and finding the closest white space to insert the delimiter, the problem is it does so even when the text is not 10 characters long.

(edit)
Attached is a sample of the expected outcome. I added a char count in column B extra clarity.

[Example Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpiNh.png)

Comment: Yes, because you set the min value to match to `1`. If you need to make sure there is at least 10, try `RX.Pattern = "(^.{10," & CharsBeforeDelim & "}?\s)(?!$)"`. Note `(?=.+)` = `(?!$)`, just makes sure it is not the end of a line/string.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I tried replacing your pattern but it doesn't insert the delimiter in the nearest space before the max char limit. I double checked by going to regex101.com to test the pattern and it doesn't give me any match.

Comment: Sure, but you need to decide what your requirements are.

Comment: If my requirements are max char as 20, and i have strings like, {"marry had a little lamb", "little sheep", "I have twent4 characters", "john smithsonberrypie"}  - Then I would expect my output to be: marry had a little//lamb//little sheep//i have twent4//characters//john//smithsonberrypie

Comment: Interesting .. You may not need regex then... May be loops, IFs and splits. Better you present a screen shot of what it looks like and what is desired result

Comment: @Naresh Thanks for the input. I've added a sample screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. Following function will join text in the selected range in a given column as desired. you can mention desired length say 20 in strLen parameter and delimiter say "//" in dChar parameter.

```
Option Explicit

Function JoinText(myRng As Range, strLen As Long, dChar As String) As String
Dim myRngVal As Variant, cellArr() As String
Dim cellJoinStr As String, i As Long, j As Long

myRngVal = myRng.Value
cellJoinStr = ""

For i = 1 To myRng.Cells.Count
    If myRng.Cells(i) <> "" Then
    cellJoinStr = cellJoinStr & dChar
    End If
    If myRng.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        cellArr = Split(myRng.Value, " ", , vbTextCompare)
        Else
        cellArr = Split(myRngVal(i, 1), " ", , vbTextCompare)
    End If
    For j = 0 To UBound(cellArr)
        
        If Len(cellJoinStr) + Len(cellArr(j)) _
            - InStrRev(cellJoinStr, dChar, -1, vbTextCompare) + 1 < strLen + 2 Then
            cellJoinStr = cellJoinStr & " " & cellArr(j)
            Else
            cellJoinStr = cellJoinStr & dChar & cellArr(j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

JoinText = cellJoinStr

End Function
```

Not that each new row will begin with "// " (including space which you can remove with substitute function) and within cell each segment of max 20 characters will begin with "//"

Also, check [Total number of characters that a cell can contain](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

[image]

Comment: it works great. Do you know how to fix it so that it doesn't leave an extra "//" if the string in Col A is empty?

Comment: @user2993905 edited answer .. Please note that I have replaced "//" in the function with dChar. .. So the new function in worksheet will be like JoinText(A1:A3,20,"//") making it more flexible .. you can use dChar of your choice.. Also, you being a new member I would suggest to [please accept/ upvote if this answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%20To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A%20%201%20Choose,un-accept%20the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.%20More%20)

Comment: @user2993905 Happy to help.. excited to learn :)